# NoClassDefFoundError exception with SpringBoot in Elasticsearch7.3

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch

I try to create document via high level rest client with:

```
    Map<String, Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
    jsonMap.put("name", "Bob");
    jsonMap.put("id", "123456");
    IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("lead").id("123456").source(jsonMap);
    client.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

But it throws a NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/util/BytesRefIterator.
The elastic version is 7.3.2.
That's the elasticsearch dependency in my pom.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

The full stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-20" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/util/BytesRefIterator
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest.source(IndexRequest.java:397)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest.source(IndexRequest.java:377)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest.source(IndexRequest.java:365)
    at com.sunyard.mdhome.elasticsearch.impl.MetadataDocumentBuilderImpl.createDocument(MetadataDocumentBuilderImpl.java:182)
    at com.sunyard.mdhome.elasticsearch.impl.MetadataDocumentBuilderImpl.build(MetadataDocumentBuilderImpl.java:76)
    at com.sunyard.mdhome.elasticsearch.impl.MetadataDocumentBuilderImpl.getPage(MetadataDocumentBuilderImpl.java:163)
    at com.sunyard.mdhome.elasticsearch.impl.MetadataDocumentBuilderImpl.getSyncMetadata(MetadataDocumentBuilderImpl.java:121)
    at com.sunyard.mdhome.thread.MetadataSyncThread.run(MetadataSyncThread.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefIterator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
```

The maven dependencies tree:
[maven dependencies tree 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMvI5.png)
[maven dependencies tree 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4To9S.png)

Comment: Can you please share your application's maven dependency-tree?

Comment: hi, I've uploaded maven dependency-tree as link.@Ramu

Answer (score 0):

I've found out the cause of the error. There's another dependence in this project which includes a 3.5.0 version of `lucene-core.jar`. It conflicts with the 8.1.0 version `lucene-core.jar` in elasticsearch. The program uses the 3.5.0 version actually while the program is running.